# Foreach statement inside a called function gives an error

Tags: php, function

I insert a `foreach()` statement, which is suppose to display year value dynamically,into a called function but the it keeps giving errors... 
This is an extract of what I am doing

```
   $display->content( 'The heading 
                    <select name="Year" id="Year">'. 
                          foreach(range(date("Y",2013) as $value){ 
                               echo "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>\n";
                           }
                     .'</select> The script ends'
           );
```

This is the error i receive any time I execute it `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in /var/www/test.php on line 140`
. Please any help to deal with this is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You are trying to concatenate a string with a `foreach` statement. That does not make sense. Run the `foreach` first, gather the output into a string and concatenate with that instead.

Comment: Also a bracket is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is syntactically invalid. The following should work.

```
$options = "";
foreach(range(date("Y",2013)) as $value)
{ 
    $options .= '<option value="'.$value.'">$value</option>';
}
$display->content( 'The heading 
                    <select name="Year" id="Year">'. 
                          $options
                    .'</select> The script ends'
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` in PHP is a statement, i.e. it is a part of a program that does not return any value. The PHP compiler complains about this by telling you that it did not expect a `foreach` keyword after a concatenation operator `.`, which needs another string to add to the previous.

You might want to move the loop out of the function call and assemble your string in a variable as follows:

```
// assemble the content first
$c = 'The heading <select name="Year" id="Year">';
foreach (range(date("Y",2013)) as $value) {
    $c .= "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>\n";
}
$c .= '</select> The script ends';

// then call your function
$display->content($c);
```

Note that this is one of the key differences to functional languages like Scala, where almost everything has a proper return type — even for or if statements.